# How reliable is Tox' caching?

Tags: jenkins, tox

I am using Tox as a wrapper around all the python code quality tools like flake8, mypy and pytest. I also invoke Tox from Jenkins.

Currently, for every `git push` we

- create a fresh Conda environment holding python=3.7 and tox
- invoke tox, which will recreate all virtual environments freshly
- remove .tox/ and the Conda environment

Due to this, running tox takes 2 seconds locally but 90 seconds in Jenkins.

I now wonder whether we are to cautious. Would it be ok to leave the .tox/ cache folder alone in Jenkin? It might be important that we have just `deps = -rrequirements-dev.txt` in `[testenv]`.

Are there other means to speed up testing with tox?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [*tox* documentation on "Dependency changes and tracking"](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/general.html#dependency-changes-and-tracking), it seems changes in a `requirements.txt` file do not trigger the rebuild of the virtual environment. So it looks like you should indeed delete the `.tox` directory or at least use the `-r, --recreate` option of tox (which might be more efficient).

Maybe you could give tox plugins such as [*tox-auto-env*](https://pypi.org/project/tox-auto-env/), or [*tox-pip-extensions*](https://pypi.org/project/tox-pip-extensions/) a try.

Don't know about the necessity of rebuilding the *conda* environment though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Tox named `detox` which enables parallel processing of `tox` pipelines. Recent versions of `tox` (I have Python 3.7.3 and tox 3.14.0) directly supply this feature.

Using `tox --parallel auto` in the Jenkins file drops the time needed from 90 seconds to 20. For my needs this is good enough and I can avoid any worries about caching issues now.