# tox, pd.read_html can't find lxml even though it is in requirements.txt

Tags: python, lxml, tox

I have some code that uses pandas.read_html which subsequently requires lxml. I added lxml (tried both just lxml and lxml>=4.5.0). But tox couldn't find the package:

```
.tox/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py:848: in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
E   ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

In my tox.ini:

```
[testenv]
# install pytest in the virtualenv where commands will be executed
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
    -rrequirements_test.txt
    coverage
```

In my requirements.txt:

```
numpy
scipy 
requests
lxml>=4.5.0
pandas
```

Any idea why this happens? This exception is not raised in my normal python development, but for some reason tox just won't be able to install it. But it has no problem with other packages.

Best,

J

Comment: Did you remove and recreate virtual environments after adding `lxml` to `requirements.txt`? `tox` doesn't automatically reinstall changed requirements.

Comment: no, not really, but it is now working but I honestly don't know what I did differently to make it work. I first tried listing all packages in tox.ini rather than using requirements.txt. It worked. Then removed that and tried requirements.txt. It still works. I honestly don't know why. At least my git changes did not show any other changes.

Comment: "*Then removed that and tried requirements.txt. It still works.*" Because `tox` cached created virtual environments with all installed packages. Removing `lxml` from `tox.ini` doesn't remove it from the cached environments.

Comment: ah, you are right. Does it mean each time I update requirements, I need to rm .tox/ first? This seems to be the problem. Please leave your answer.

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58605263/7976758

Comment: Yeah, we'll fix this with tox 4. But for now changing dependencies outside of tox.ini (requirements files, build backend files) does not trigger a recreate.